# Meaning of the Corollary 31.29 of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading CLRS and it had the following Corollary:

> If $n_1, n_2, ..., n_k$ are pairwise relatively prime and $n =  n_1n_2...n_k$ then for all integers $x$ and $a$,
>
> $$ x \equiv a \pmod {n_i}$$
>
> for $i=1,2,...,k$ if and only if
>
> $$ x \equiv a \pmod n$$

There seems to be some words missing in the theorem/corollary. Should it read:

For all integers $x$ and $a$ that satisfy the equation:

$$ x \equiv a \pmod {n_i}$$

we have that it implies that:

$$ x \equiv a \pmod n $$

is also true. Furthermore, the converse is true too.

In other words, if: $ x \equiv a \pmod {n_i}$ for some integer $a$ and $x$, then it implies that $ x \equiv a \pmod n $ and visa versa. i.e. If $ x \equiv a \pmod n $ is true then $ x \equiv a \pmod {n_i}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the meaning is exactly that you mentioned. "If and only if" means that the implication is true in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

It means something like $x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ and $x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ if and only if $x \equiv 2 \pmod{35}$